# case of "Bus" in "Wissen sie, wann der Bus kommt?"

Tags: grammatical-case

I know that

> der Bus = the bus

and in the question

> Wissen sie, wann der Bus kommt?

I would have thought that seeing the verb "kommen" is being used, the article of the noun "Bus" would be "den" i.e. in the accusative.

The idea I had was:

> Wissen sie, wann den Bus kommt?

Why is the initial question in the nominative and not in the accusative?

Comment: "Den" geht nur bei "Sehen Sie den Bus kommen?"

Answer (score 9):

That is because in sentences as

> Wann kommt der Bus? *or* Der Bus kommt wann?
>
> Gleich kommt der Bus. *or* Der Bus kommt gleich.

the item *der Bus* is the subject. It's the thing that performs the action of *kommen*. It's not performed *on the bus*, but the bus does it itself. So,
the verb *kommen* has no objects. *Wann* and *gleich* are adverbials of time.

Same for your example. The different word order is because it's a subordinate clause but still, *der Bus* is the subject in that clause.